# How to ask the user which students grade they want to look up. And print that student’s grade from the input listed

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, user-input

**The code I wrote is directly below and my question is under it.**

```
student= {}
for i in range(5):
    name = input("Add students name: ")
    grade = input("Add students grade: ")
    student[name] = grade
print(student)
```

**My question would be easier to show you and I would like the output to be what is listed below however I can't seem to get the last two lines.**

"Enter a name: Sue

Enter a grade: 90

Enter a name: Bob

Enter a grade: 60

Enter a name: Kim

Enter a grade: 55

Enter a name: Jim

Enter a grade: 100

Enter a name: Sarah

Enter a grade: 95

{'Jim': 100.0, 'Kim ': 55.0, 'Sue': 90.0, 'Sarah': 95.0, 'Bob': 60.0}

Type a name to lookup in the dictionary: Jim

The grade is:  100.0"

**If you can help me get what is listed above it would be very helpful. Thanks.**

Comment: Just add another *input* to get *studnet_name* then passing to ```student[student_name]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code for this problem below.

```py
student= {}
for i in range(3):
    name = input("Add students name: ")
    grade = input("Add students grade: ")
    student[name] = grade
lookup_name = input("Type a name to lookup in the dictionary: ")
try:
    lookup_grade = student[lookup_name]
    print(lookup_grade)
except:
    print('name not in list')
```

Output:

```
Add students name: A
Add students grade: 50
Add students name: B
Add students grade: 60
Add students name: C
Add students grade: 70
Type a name to lookup in the dictionary: B
60
```

If it helps, please accept the answer.